# Prove the complex number identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I was wondering how to solve
$$
|z| + |m| 
= \biggl|\, \frac{z+m}{2} - u \,\biggr| 
+ \biggl|\, \frac{z+m}{2} + u \,\biggr|,
$$
where $u = \sqrt{z\,m}$.

*I tried converting the left side by squaring the absolute values, however it leads me nowhere. Can anybody help me with the problem above. Thank You!*

Comment: Is that intended to be $|z|+|m| = \left|\frac{z+m}{2}-u\right|+\left|\frac{z+m}{2}+u\right|$, where $u = \sqrt{z\times m}$? And are $z$ and $m$ complex values? (I would probably just write $u = \sqrt{zm}$, by the way, but you might need to define that more precisely.)

Comment: Is that $\times$ the product of two complex numbers?  Then $u$ and $-u$ are the two square roots of $zm$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Good point.

Comment: @BrianTung. Precisely! Both z and m are complex numbers.

Comment: Hint: try expanding $(\sqrt{z} + \sqrt{m})^2 / 2$ and $(\sqrt{z} - \sqrt{m})^2 / 2$, where $\sqrt{z}$ and $\sqrt{m}$ are square roots of $z$ and $m$ such that $u = \sqrt{z}\sqrt{m}$.

Comment: Hint: let $z=u^2, m=w^2$ then the equality is just $2\left(|v|^2 + |w|^2\right) 
= |v+w|^2 + |v-w|^2\,$, which you might have seen before.

Comment: @dxiv Hi! Can you please write a complete solution?

Comment: @Novichok Lookup the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law), written with complex numbers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710612/for-z-1-z-2-in-mathbb-c-prove-that-z-1z-22z-1-z-22-2z-12z-2) for example. You have there all you need to put together a nice self-answer.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you so much! I got the answer!